# Unknown redirect & slow page load

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

Hello: I am hosting a website with GoDaddy's "Deluxe Linux" package. Of late, I noticed my website is loading nearly 10x slower. As I begin to debug, I noticed the following redirect occurring however nothing in my script would be causing it.

It hits the URL, www.domain.com, then a 302 fires to www.domain.com/39dnda, then another 302 back to www.doamin.com ???

The first 302 is random each time...

You can see the images here:
http://yfrog.com/4jredirectvp

Comment: Can you provide your domain name for analysis?

Comment: Change your host. GoDaddy's service is abhorrent!

Comment: I host with MediaTemple simply because of their (dv) service, but I never had a single problem with GoDaddy or their customer service... ever.

Comment: Good luck transferring your domain if its registered with them. They'll squeeze ya dry

Answer (score 1):

From what I could find on Google, this is just a sad reality of GoDaddy's hosting. Calling their tech support may be helpful, but others have found it unsuccessful.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=4248d0de0a3b0500&hl=en
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=0027845188f3a4b9&hl=en